# Defining dimen resource to different screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been doing a lot of internet  searching to make an activity layout fit on multiple screen sizes. Layout weights does the job but it is not my requirement. I want to do it using `dp` values. Now i know you can define `dimen` resource in `dimen.xml` file in `values-ldpi` , `values-mdpi` , `values-hdpi` and `values-xhdpi` folders for `ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi`,`xhdpi` type of screens.

**Problem**

I have a header (`LinearLayout`) on top of each of my activity layout. on `ldpi` device the height is `53dp`. I have defined different heights in different `dimen.xml` file. For example for `mdpi` i have defined `60dp`. It is also working. Problem came when i test it on `5.1'' WVGA (480 x 800: mdpi)`. It is an mdpi screen to it should select height from `values-mdpi/dimen.xml` and should be the same as any `mdpi` screen. **but it is not** . I want to know why is that. isn't the `values-mdpi` folder is for all `mdpi` screens?

Comment: Why the down voting ?

Comment: Aren't you confusing **dp** with **px**? Because normally, dps are set only once and fo all, since `they will be scaled automatically`. In **rare** occasions you might want to fix them for specific densities or resolutions (which are different things).

Answer (score 2):

i think you should try to change folder name from values-.. to values than values-sw360dp,values-sw480dp,values-sw600dp and so on as per your screen requirement and than put different dimens.xml file for each screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can't go by screen size to determine density-  some devices claim they're one density even when they probably should be a lower (or higher) one.  The only thing you can be certain of is that they will be consistent.  That's one of the reasons why you don't layout everything in dp.

You said layout weights work.  Use them.  Using dps for sizing of elements is almost always wrong.

Comment: The problem with using layout weights is the i have an EditText below the screen and when i click it to edit text soft keyboard pushes the layout above with my header. and i don't want that because my save button is on my header.

Comment: Set your layout to softinputmode resize, and it will resize your app rather than pan the header up

Comment: where to set this property? and doesn't resize means adjusting all things in available space? like soft keyboard comes up and my header becomes small.

Comment: In the manifest, on your activity.  And yes, it resizes your entire app into the space above the keyboard.  It does a full layout pass, so it isn't just shrinking-  it will evaluate how your app would look as if they space over the keyboard was the entire screen.  If you set up your app using normal layout techniques it will mostly just cut out extra data.  If you're using dp you're screwed though-  that's one of the reasons why you aren't supposed to do that.